# WPF Page Navigation windows icon

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am using WPF page navigation.

How can I add an icon to the windows?

How can I control the height and width of the windows?

Thank you.

Comment: If I use Windows, I know where it is, but not Page.

Comment: OK i know already, WindowHeight="400" WindowWidth="400".